# Large unwanted spaces between elements in Kivy layout

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to the world of UIs and am using Kivy as my first framework. I am trying to create an application that displays a series of images in a scrollable grid.

To that end, I have two issues:

- There are very large gaps between the images
- The window does not react well to being re-sized and cuts off content

I have tried all manner of things to address the first issue, but have had no luck. For the second one, I was able to poorly-address the issue by using:

```
Window.size = (1920,1080)
```

While it redeuces the severity of the symptoms, it doesn't address the core issue of the application not actually re-sizing its elements when the window size is changed.

```
import pathlib
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from providers import Provider


class UIApp(App):
    def build(self):

        prov = Provider() # An API-interfacing object that returns a list of objects that contain image meta-data
        prov.set_limit(10) # Only ten results
        entry_list = prov.search() # Returns a list of objects that contain an image URL. Images may be any size.

        gl = GridLayout(cols=2, spacing=0, size_hint_y=100)
        gl.bind(minimum_height=gl.setter('height'))

        for entry in entry_list:
            print(entry.image_full)
            file_ext = pathlib.Path(entry.image_full).suffix.replace(".", "")
            if file_ext == "mp4":
                continue

            gl.add_widget(AsyncImage(source=entry.image_full, size_hint=(0.1, 0.1)))

        root = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
        root.add_widget(gl)
        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    UIApp().run()
```

Comment: Please add an output image.That is going to help us what type of output are you getting exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `minimum_height` in a `GridLayout` when you are using `size_hint` for the height of its children. I suggest setting an explicit height for each `AsyncImgage`.